# If class instances are always passed by reference?

Tags: python-3.x, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I am implementing a singly LinkedList in Python3. The program assigns "current_node" to "previous_node" and then it changes "current_node" to "current_node.next". I expect that this change is applied to "previous_node" as well but it does not.

```py
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

a = [7, 8, 11, 3]

fst_node, sec_node, thd_node, frt_node = ListNode(a[0]), ListNode(a[1]), ListNode(a[2]), ListNode(a[3])

fst_node.next = sec_node
sec_node.next = thd_node
thd_node.next = frt_node

current_node  = sec_node
previous_node = current_node
print(previous_node, current_node)
current_node  = current_node.next
print(previous_node, current_node)
```

Comment: Before you make the final assignment both `current_node` and `previous_node` refer to the same object. Then you make `current_node` refer to a different object. Previous node isn't affected.

Comment: FWIW, you can do `fst_node, sec_node, thd_node, frt_node = map(ListNode, a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference (variable) and the object itself are not the same thing.

You can change the variable to point to another object, but not the object will be changed.

```
objRef = someObject
anotherObjRef = objRef
objRef = anotherObject
# anotherObjRef will still point to someObject!
```

But, if you modify something in the object (through the reference), the object will be modified, therefore you will see the new value in all references:

```
objRef = someObject
anotherObjRef = objRef
objRef.someData = something
# anotherObjRef.someData is something!
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
current_node  = sec_node
previous_node = current_node  # current_node points to the same object as previous_node
print(previous_node, current_node)
current_node  = current_node.next  # changes where current_node points to
print(previous_node, current_node)
```

Do you notice that `previous_node` is not being reassigned here? Only `current_node` is. This is still pass-by-reference, you are just changing what `current_node` references and leaving `precious_node` alone.